# Why use autologin cookie if there is session ID?

Tags: php, session, logging, cookies

Could someone please explain me what the autologin cookie (autologin functionality) is used for? I've done some searching and found the following answer on the similar question on some other forum:

> If autologin is turned off, when the user closes his/her browser, or after a certain amount of time (configured PHP engine), the session data is destroyed, and thus, as a side effect, the memory of the user being logged-in is lost ==> in effect the user is logged-off. 
>   The autologin feature is there to override this behaviour in case you don't want users to explicitly login ("manually", i.e. type in their user id and password) each time they access your WEB site. To do so, the information about the user being logged-in is stored in something "more permanent" than the PHP session: a cookie.

I'm interested in this phrase: `If autologin is turned off, when the user closes his/her browser....the session data is destroyed`. Why does he say that the sessionid is destroyed? It's not destroyed if it's not yet due to destruction by the time set by server.

And I don't understand this phrase `To do so, the information about the user being logged-in is stored in something "more permanent" than the PHP session: a cookie.`. Isn't sessionId is just another cookie?

Based on that answer I can only suppose that usually autologin cookie has larger lifetime than sessions and this is the only reason to use autologin. So it means that if I set indefinite lifetime for sessionId cookie there is no need for autologin, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, a "session cookie" has two meanings:

- a cookie with an undefined lifetime which is discarded at the end of the current "browsing session", i.e. when the browser is closed (note that that's not necessarily true anymore either though)
- a cookie holding a session id

A "PHP session" here means a data file stored on the server, named with a random id, which (the id) is given to the client in a cookie (which may be a "session" (short lived) cookie or not). You *can* configure PHP's session handling and the session cookie particulars so both the server side session and the respective cookie will be valid virtually indefinitely. This would be a perfectly valid "permanent logon" solution in itself, nothing more needed.

However, server-side sessions take up space, and should also be discarded when not in use anymore to keep the pool of currently in-use session ids as small as possible (otherwise it would be pretty easy to hijack a random session). So you typically don't want to use a standard PHP session for permanent login purposes. You would rather generate a very long random token which you save in the database, rather than in the general session store, which is mostly really to deal with computing resources more efficiently. You still use standard short lived sessions for the actual active logged in user, but to identify the user long-term you use a separate id/cookie stored elsewhere.

> when the user closes his/her browser....the session data is destroyed

This is patently wrong. The *session cookie* may or may not be discarded by the browser, which means the client loses his "connection" with the server side session store. The server side session will *eventually* be garbage collected. But it will certainly not immediately vanish as soon as a browser is closed.

> To do so, the information about the user being logged-in is stored in something "more permanent" than the PHP session: a cookie.

Again, a PHP session *can* be made extremely permanent if you bother to configure it so, the defaults are simply somewhat short. Also, as you said, the last part of that statement makes absolutely no sense, since a "PHP session" also includes the use of a cookie (typically), and this cookie *can* be made pretty permanent if, again, you bother to change the defaults.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot! A few questions - how do you set a cookie with undefined lifetime - is it `lifetime:0`? What considerations should I take into account when deciding which model to use - permanent session cookie without login or shortlived sessin cookie with autologin permanent cookie?